# Bash: How to find and replace word in files name

Tags: bash, replace, find

For finding all files which include `foo` in name.

`find / -name *foo*`

for example result is

```
/etc/lib/football
/var/log/some/somefooandother
/home/me/anotherfoo
/etc/all/files/includingfooinnamefoo
```

But how i can replace all `foo` -> `bar` in names of those files?

```
/etc/lib/bartball
/var/log/some/somebarandother
/home/me/anotherbar
/etc/all/files/includingbarinnamebar
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this:

```
for i in $(ls | grep "foo"); do
j="$(echo $i | sed s/foo/bar/)"
mv "$i" "$j"
done;
```

- Find file containing string foo and store to a variable i

  ```
      for i in $(ls | grep "foo");
  ```
- Rename and store to another variable j

  ```
  j="$(echo $i | sed s/foo/bar/)"
  ```
- Rename file name using mv

  ```
  mv "$i" "$j"
  ```

I have checked this on my system and it worked perfectly but it's always safe to backup your data before you proceed. You never know what a typo (mine or yours) can cause.